# link address not working across

Tags: express, pug

I have a share layout that use across the website

Inside the layout.jade I a have a link:

```
a(href='../user/profile') Profile
```

but when on page `http://hello.com/member/list/profile` will not be able to link back to the page `profile (http://hello.com/user/profile)` using the above link.

Comment: Where does it actually link to then? Also shouldn't it be `../../user/profile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use "/fullpath/user/profile" it will refer to the root directory. If you use this version of linking, it won't matter where you are on the site, it will link to the same two links. "/user/profile" or "/member/list/profile".